# Does "of complete honesty" mean exactly the same as "completely honest"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

The structure `to be + of + noun` is usually taken to mean the same as `to be + the relevant adjective.` For example,

> The speech is of complete honesty.

means the same as

> The speech is completely honest.

Yet, I feel a slight difference between their meanings. It might be due to difference in emphasis. But I cannot spot the difference. Do they mean exactly the same? Is it like that one is sometimes preferred over the other?

Comment: The local district attorney might be completely honest when she states that she will not prosecute you for Crime A. However, complete honesty would be revealing that the federal prosecutor *will.*

Comment: @Davo So, what?

Comment: So, one can be completely honest (about something) without expressing complete honesty (about related issues).

Comment: Davo is saying that telling only the truth is not necessarily the same as telling the whole (relevant) truth. However, 'The speech is of complete honesty' sounds pretty unidiomatic.

Comment: I think a *person* might be more natural in the subject position for this pair of predicates--even though that might open the door to the somewhat old-fashioned sense of *honest* as *chaste*--with implications particularly for the *of complete honesty* form.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What about with other subjects, for example,  "she/they/the program is/are of complete honesty"?

Comment: They sound worse. Check on Google for the relative occurrences of "He is a man of complete integrity" and "He is of complete integrity" to see that the inclusion of a sensible nominal complement can make a big difference to acceptability, then check "He is a man of complete honesty" and "He is of complete honesty" to see how slight changes can affect idiomaticity enormously.

Comment: To be completely honest, there are differences, but they're too subtle to explain.

Answer (score 1):

To this native American English speaker, the first form is slightly stilted and archaic. Examples:

- "To be of good cheer" vs. "To be cheerful"
- "To be of no value" vs. "To be valueless"